# Eclipse Luna - Generate getters and setters insertion point after last method by default

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to set the insertion point after last method by default? When I generate g/setters, I always have to choose the insertion point and it's pretty annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if in your class fields were added first then methods. Assuming your class structure is like this.

```
class {
  Field 1;
  ..
  ..
  Field n;

  method1() {
  }
  ...
  methodn() {
  }
}
```

open the Getter setter dialog in the **insertion point** combo box select **Last member** option for the first time, then onwards this dialog will remember the option and all getter setter will be appended after the last member.